# Providing the x,y,width and height value, how do I get the svg transform matrix that scales from center

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I have a code that generates gif file from svg using php and imagemagick.
Below is the sample svg code.
Assuming the animation is going to be created by tweening the scale transform scale value from 0 to 1, how do I get the transform matrix that'll center the transform origin using svg element properties x,y,width, height?

Note: I do all the computation with php and the conversion to raster using Imagemagick which I dont think supports the css transform-origin style.

Currently, the transition starts from the left. I want to translate it using matrix.

The link below is the example gif of the current implementation
https://i.imgur.com/juMX3uD.gifv

**Transformed SVG**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="layer" overflow="visible" 
stroke="none" stroke-width="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
id="layer_1547759965149_0506449632092969" width="135.24545454545" 
height="110.9375" x="86.896363636365" y="84.286250000001"><g 
    id="translateLayer" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"><g id="effectLayer" 
transform="rotate(44.596407613288 67.622727272727 55.46875)" 
fill="#FF4400"><svg viewBox="0 0 657.01 569" width="100%" height="100%" 
preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="hidden"><g id="Layer_2" data- 
name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><polygon points="0 569 
328.49 0 657.01 569 0 569"/></g></g></svg></g></g></svg>
```

**The transformation happens here**

```html
<g id="translateLayer" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)"></g>
```

Comment: I think there should be some transform-origin property. However, to get a transform matrix with a "built-in" origin, you generally translate (move) the system to get the intended transform origin to (0;0), do all the other transforms and move it back (negative translation). All the steps are joined into one matrix by multiplying all the matrixes in the order of transforms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: You can also set the viewport to have the origin in the center. (I've not done very much with SVG, but I am familiar with VR 3D development.)

Comment: I guess that is css property. I already stated that the rasterization library, imagemagick currently doesnt interpret css values. Take a look at the included GIF link. I want the scaling to transform from center . That is achievable using matrix translation but I just dont know how to go about calculating it. Provide example php or js code if possible

Comment: I remember you actually can set the viewport of the SVG somehow with negative top/left.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, view the gif to understand better. transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" is where the animation happens. The scale values is changed overtime . The center origin can be achieved using the translate matrix values . My problem is how to get that as am not so good with matrixes

Comment: It's confusing that the gif is scaling and the shown svg has a rotation. You might have to clarify why the SVG code is different to the GIF

Comment: The scaling happens on the parent g element with id translateLayer. Look at the transform property there. The gif is produced by changing the matrix value for scale from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of fighting with code, I got the fix I was looking for.

Below is the final matrix calculation I implemented

```
x = (x/2);
y = (y/2);
matrix(scaleX 0 0 scaleY (x-scaleX*x) (y-scaleY*y));
```

https://i.imgur.com/qAaZ1Tl.gifv

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to apply transformations with a specific without changing the user coordinate system of the SVG by setting a `viewBox` which could make it easier.

The origin is the center point of the triangle. That's the half `width` and 2/3 `height` of the image in this case.

So why not just apply subsequent transforms rather than struggeling with matrix calculation? And the `rotation` function even takes origin parameters.

```js
    var
      svg = document.getElementById('layer_1547759965149_0506449632092969'),
      sca = svg.getElementById('translateLayer'),
      rot = svg.getElementById('effectLayer'),
      deg = 0,

      cx = svg.getAttribute('width') / 2,
      cy = svg.getAttribute('height') * 2/3
    ;

    function rotate()
    {
      deg++;
      let scale = 1 + Math.sin(deg/180*Math.PI);
      rot.setAttribute('transform',  (()=>`rotate(${deg} ${cx} ${cy})`)());
      sca.setAttribute('transform',  (()=>`translate(${cx} ${cy}) scale(${scale} ${scale}) translate(-${cx} -${cy})`)());
    }
    setInterval(rotate, 50);
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="layer" id="layer_1547759965149_0506449632092969"
         overflow="visible"
         stroke="none" stroke-width="0" preserveAspectRatio="none"
         width="135.24545454545" height="110.9375"
         x="86.896363636365" y="84.286250000001">
      <!--<g id="translateLayer" transform="matrix(0 67.622727272725 0  0 73.95833333333333   0)">-->
      <g id="translateLayer" transform="matrix(2 0 0 2 0.5 0.5)" transform-origin(200,100)>
        <g id="effectLayer"
           fill="#FF4400">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 657.01 569" width="100%" height="100%"
               preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="hidden">
            <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
              <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
                <polygon points="0 569  328.49 0   657.01 569   0 569"/>
              </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```